How to integrate C# legacy code into Cpp environment?
A program that parses parameters from a custom config file is written in C#. Since I dont want to rewrite the parser (fairly complex), I am looking to intergrate it into my Cpp program.
I've looked into the following approaches:
Using Visual Studio C++/Cli

Generally the methology is to put the existing C# code into a .dll and writing a wrapper project in Visual Studio C++/Cli environment. This wrapper project can then be integrated in a native Cpp program.
Since I am working in a VSCode environment, I had troubles integrating the C++/Cli project into my VSCode CMake project. An existing solution in a Visual Studio environment can be found from this github.
Using interop techniques

Putting the existing C# code into a .dll and loading the functions with
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"MyCScode.dll"); also appears to be a simple approach, yet my program didnt find the src of the functions when loading the library.
So which way would you recommend? Is there an easier way to do it?

Modify the parser to output the data in a more useful/simple format for the C++ program to use as its input?

@Neil The input config file format can not be changed due to norms. I might need to rewrite the C# code into cpp but I find it odd, that there is no simple solution to this rather common task.

I didn't say change the input to the C# program.  Modify the C# program to output a configuration file that is easy for the C++ program to use as it's input configuration.  TBH, your problem is not common, the common case is to use 'old' C++ code in a 'new' C# project (managed C++/IJW, your option #1), which is why that is supported.  Option 2 will not work because C# is not a simple DLL, with exposed entry points, like a C or C++ DLL can be.  C# is a managed virtual machine runtime, that dynamically creates executable code at runtime.

If you want to run any .net code in a native process you need to host the CLR. This seem like a quite uncommon thing to do, so I would not expect a huge amount of resources. Calling native code from a managed process is way more common, but is still not supported all that well. But I agree with Neil, parsing files should be a solved problem by now, with standardized formats and libraries for just about every language.

Thank you both, that was actually great input. I found it hard to find documentary that helps me finding a proper approach.

How about creating a C interface for the C# library? You can then call C interface from C++. With that way, you can than call the parser from different languages other than C++ also, since C has rather simpler mangling mechanism.
